# How to pivot columns to rows mapping values for each year accordingly in R

Tags: r

I have data in columns18-column 141. Column18,20,22 and so on has years such as 2021,2020,2019 till 1960 and column19,21,23 and so on has values for the corresponding years. I have one more column with source names such as Renewable Energy consumption, Renewable Energy Production etc. I want to make this energy source rows as columns and and years columns as rows with years from 2021-1960 with values mapped to each year as per the source.

I tried pivot, joins etc and nothing is working for me in R.

I am pasting the data below - the actual and the expected data

Actual Data
[image: Actual Data]

How I want it to be
[image: How I want it to be]

could you help me with a code in R to reshape this data

Comment: Hi, @deepa palariya, and welcome to stack overflow! So that we can best help you, please kindly edit your question to follow the standard S.O. format: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Thanks!

Comment: Please read about [how to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly. Include a sample of your data by pasting the output of `dput(<your data frame>)` into your post or `dput(head(<your data frame>))` if you have a large data frame. Also include code you have tried, any relevant errors, and expected output. If you cannot post your data, then post code for creating representative data. [Do not post images of code and/or data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6382434).